# Cannot debug azure functions in VS Code, error running func host start, but can manually run "func host start" from powershell

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am experiencing difficulty debugging an azure functions project in VS Code.
I created an azure project in using func init.
When i click Debug from the run menu, the project builds, but on trying to run "func host start" the following error manifests:

```
> Executing task: func host start <

-Command : The term '-Command' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or opera
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ -Command func host start
+ ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-Command:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If i run func host start manually from powershell it works fine.

So far i have tried:

- updating the function core tools.
- updating .net
- uninstalling and reinstalling vs code
- ensuring the path to the core tools is in the path environment variables
- running vs code as admin

Would appreciate any assistance figuring this out.

Update, adding screenshot of error:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of googling found a suggestion to change the default terminal in vs code.
it was set to powershell, but changing it to command prompt resolved the issue.

[image]

Setting is found in the command pallet by typing "Terminal: Select Default Profile.
This brings up a list of available terminals, command prompt, gitbash, windows powershell, .net powershell.

selecting command prompt allows debugging.

thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solution of @wilson_smyth . Instead of "command prompt", selecting "Javascript Debug Terminal" option worked for me.[image]

Comment: This also worked for me. I guess depends on which language you are coding the default terminal profile changes, i.e. I am using Typescript therefore, Javascript Debug Terminal worked for me. Also make sure to close the VS and then open it again so it will work.

Answer (score 0):

We need to make sure that below two are available in our VS Code:

1. Azure Tools Extension
2. Azure function code tools.

After adding them we can execute the code normally to check if we have any errors, later set the breakpoint, and hit F5 to launch the into debug, now we need to run the function in the terminal, as in my case, I use interpreter as Python, I run it as below:

[Reference document](https://swaminathanvetri.in/2020/02/07/debugging-azure-functions-locally-in-vs-code/#:%7E:text=Debugging%20Azure%20Functions%20Locally%20in%20VS%20Code%20Step,3%20%3A%20Debug%20using%20Azure%20Functions%20Core%20Tools)

[image]

We can try this method rather running it from power shell terminal.

Now the error which you are getting is related to packages missing. Also make sure to connect to your Azure AD from [PS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest&tabs=azure-powershell) first before executing.

Comment: I tried this but still getting the same issue. i dont think connecting to azure is needed as its running on the local emulator. ive added a screenshot of the error in the original post

Comment: Further update, the function runs fine from visual studio 2019. i can also run it via command line. its just trying it via visual studio code thats not working. vs code , function tools have both been reinstalled but issue remains.

Comment: Looks like the issue exists in VS-Code configurations, as you mentioned that you've reinstalled, so can you check .json files which are the dependencies for Azure functions to run locally. And compare them with Visual Studio dependency files. 
if this doesn't works, try to reinstall VS-Code and install Azure Functions Core Tools.

Comment: Thanks for this. Where can i find the vs code dependency files? They are visible in visual studio 2019 solution explorer but not easily visible (to me) in vs code,